# Оптимизация вложенных циклов

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, оптимизация, numpy

Используя `best practice` необходимо оптимизировать часть рабочего кода с вложенными циклами.

Переменные l1, l2, l3, l4 содержат по 3 цифры (лотерейные шары) для каждой из категорий.

```
l1 = (bc.loc[bc['category'] == res.index[0]].index).to_list()
l2 = (bc.loc[bc['category'] == res.index[1]].index).to_list()
l3 = (bc.loc[bc['category'] == res.index[2]].index).to_list()
l4 = (bc.loc[bc['category'] == res.index[3]].index).to_list()
```

Далее в циклах осуществляется перебор всех возможных комбинаций шаров из списка l1, l2, l3, l4. Из каждого списка берется ровно один шар. Итого возможных комбинаций 3^4 = 81.

Ниже приведенны ожидаемые данные. Пятый и шестой элемент каждой строки содержит случайные числа и поэтому будут меняться после каждого запуска скрипта

```
[[32, 1, 23, 29, 21, 20],
 [32, 1, 23, 8, 10, 21],
 [32, 1, 23, 28, 21, 11],
 [32, 1, 12, 29, 10, 18],
 [32, 1, 12, 8, 13, 15],
 [32, 1, 12, 28, 11, 30],
 [32, 1, 15, 29, 21, 36],
 [32, 1, 15, 8, 28, 19],
 [32, 1, 15, 28, 33, 31],
 [32, 22, 23, 29, 20, 8],
 [32, 22, 23, 8, 7, 19],
 [32, 22, 23, 28, 2, 26],
 [32, 22, 12, 29, 21, 34],
 [32, 22, 12, 8, 19, 15],
 [32, 22, 12, 28, 7, 1],
 [32, 22, 15, 29, 20, 6],
 [32, 22, 15, 8, 10, 24],
 [32, 22, 15, 28, 24, 1],
 [32, 13, 23, 29, 24, 27],
 [32, 13, 23, 8, 1, 20],
 [32, 13, 23, 28, 6, 1],
 [32, 13, 12, 29, 3, 14],
 [32, 13, 12, 8, 14, 33],
 [32, 13, 12, 28, 8, 17],
 [32, 13, 15, 29, 28, 12],
 [32, 13, 15, 8, 20, 19],
 [32, 13, 15, 28, 30, 36],
 [6, 1, 23, 29, 19, 13],
 [6, 1, 23, 8, 26, 27],
 [6, 1, 23, 28, 19, 21],
 [6, 1, 12, 29, 7, 20],
 [6, 1, 12, 8, 23, 30],
 [6, 1, 12, 28, 15, 20],
 [6, 1, 15, 29, 27, 16],
 [6, 1, 15, 8, 18, 7],
 [6, 1, 15, 28, 23, 25],
 [6, 22, 23, 29, 4, 34],
 [6, 22, 23, 8, 19, 25],
 [6, 22, 23, 28, 18, 33],
 [6, 22, 12, 29, 7, 16],
 [6, 22, 12, 8, 31, 3],
 [6, 22, 12, 28, 30, 14],
 [6, 22, 15, 29, 9, 1],
 [6, 22, 15, 8, 16, 19],
 [6, 22, 15, 28, 10, 32],
 [6, 13, 23, 29, 9, 4],
 [6, 13, 23, 8, 19, 10],
 [6, 13, 23, 28, 7, 5],
 [6, 13, 12, 29, 5, 4],
 [6, 13, 12, 8, 14, 21],
 [6, 13, 12, 28, 5, 7],
 [6, 13, 15, 29, 26, 14],
 [6, 13, 15, 8, 25, 1],
 [6, 13, 15, 28, 35, 31],
 [27, 1, 23, 29, 7, 3],
 [27, 1, 23, 8, 10, 25],
 [27, 1, 23, 28, 35, 33],
 [27, 1, 12, 29, 15, 2],
 [27, 1, 12, 8, 35, 11],
 [27, 1, 12, 28, 11, 5],
 [27, 1, 15, 29, 17, 30],
 [27, 1, 15, 8, 6, 31],
 [27, 1, 15, 28, 25, 4],
 [27, 22, 23, 29, 31, 21],
 [27, 22, 23, 8, 36, 12],
 [27, 22, 23, 28, 7, 18],
 [27, 22, 12, 29, 23, 7],
 [27, 22, 12, 8, 11, 15],
 [27, 22, 12, 28, 36, 1],
 [27, 22, 15, 29, 26, 13],
 [27, 22, 15, 8, 16, 12],
 [27, 22, 15, 28, 25, 2],
 [27, 13, 23, 29, 19, 33],
 [27, 13, 23, 8, 10, 14],
 [27, 13, 23, 28, 16, 7],
 [27, 13, 12, 29, 16, 17],
 [27, 13, 12, 8, 23, 32],
 [27, 13, 12, 28, 26, 30],
 [27, 13, 15, 29, 7, 10],
 [27, 13, 15, 8, 22, 34],
 [27, 13, 15, 28, 12, 30]]
```

Исходный рабочий код.

```
import pandas as pd 
import argparse as ap
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
from prettytable import PrettyTable
from collections import Counter
import json
from random import randint
from itertools import chain
import operator
from functools import reduce

def ArgParser():
    parser = ap.ArgumentParser(description='Description of your program')
    parser.add_argument('-d','--draws', help='Test result', required=True)
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    return args

def main():

    args = ArgParser()
    draws = pd.read_csv(args['draws'], sep=';',header=0, index_col='draw_id')

    bc = (draws.stack().value_counts()).to_frame(name='count')
    bc['category'] = np.arange(len(bc)) // 3


    pvt = (draws.stack()
                .map(bc['category'])
                .reset_index(name='category')
                .pivot_table(index='draw_id', columns='category', 
                             aggfunc='size'))

    st = pvt.mean().to_frame(name='mean')
    st['nonzero'] = (pvt > 0).sum()
    res = st.nlargest(4, ['nonzero'])

    print(bc)

    print(st)

    print(res)

#необходимо оптимизировать код ниже

    l1 = (bc.loc[bc['category'] == res.index[0]].index).to_list()
    l2 = (bc.loc[bc['category'] == res.index[1]].index).to_list()
    l3 = (bc.loc[bc['category'] == res.index[2]].index).to_list()
    l4 = (bc.loc[bc['category'] == res.index[3]].index).to_list()

    p = []
    for b1 in l1:
        for b2 in l2: 
            for b3 in l3:
                for b4 in l4:
                    b5 = randint(1,36)
                    while b5 in [b1, b2, b3, b4]: b5 = randint(1,36)
                    b6 = randint(1,36)
                    while b6 in [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5]: b6 = randint(1,36)
                    p.append([b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6])

    print(p)

    print('The End')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Исходные данные

```
draw_id;ball1;ball2;ball3;ball4;ball5;ball6;ball7
1;9;11;17;29;30;33;36
2;5;6;9;11;15;33;28
3;4;5;10;14;20;30;8
4;4;21;22;25;26;36;6
5;1;11;13;17;24;29;36
6;2;17;22;24;27;30;1
7;4;15;26;28;29;35;34
8;12;22;24;26;31;33;2
9;6;9;16;24;33;34;17
10;3;8;12;19;27;31;1
11;4;5;7;9;14;20;25
12;9;20;32;33;35;36;22
13;16;19;23;25;29;32;12
14;6;10;11;17;33;35;15
15;1;5;16;19;22;28;33
16;3;6;7;8;16;29;12
17;1;3;10;19;24;32;23
18;9;25;27;29;33;35;22
19;7;13;17;18;21;34;6
20;7;14;18;20;27;33;28
21;1;3;5;8;22;23;25
22;4;5;13;19;28;34;11
23;3;24;26;32;35;36;14
24;2;7;18;22;30;32;4
25;5;22;28;30;31;33;3
26;1;4;6;28;31;32;13
27;7;10;15;18;23;30;8
28;6;10;12;16;18;19;4
29;9;12;16;21;23;27;3
30;6;15;18;19;25;29;2
31;4;7;22;28;29;30;15
32;3;7;14;18;33;35;29
33;4;14;21;23;28;29;30
34;2;5;9;21;26;27;20
35;1;3;9;11;13;17;27
36;11;13;15;28;32;35;18
37;3;11;16;21;28;35;15
38;1;2;12;13;14;15;6
39;5;10;13;16;18;21;20
40;1;4;18;23;32;36;7
41;6;9;13;17;18;35;23
42;11;13;19;23;24;27;12
43;2;3;8;14;32;35;25
44;1;5;12;14;21;25;9
45;2;4;15;25;28;31;9
46;19;21;23;26;30;35;2
47;11;16;22;23;24;30;8
48;8;9;11;27;30;35;32
49;1;15;22;26;31;32;25
50;3;5;8;12;16;21;7
51;7;8;13;21;22;32;30
52;1;4;8;14;27;30;12
53;2;16;20;22;27;30;21
54;1;5;16;25;27;36;22
55;4;26;28;30;32;33;6
56;5;10;13;18;24;27;29
57;1;4;5;8;22;25;28
58;3;11;24;27;29;34;17
59;1;2;6;9;14;23;32
60;5;10;12;15;24;33;22
61;5;12;15;23;24;32;18
62;2;5;11;13;25;28;10
63;8;13;18;19;27;31;12
64;7;9;11;23;32;34;22
65;2;4;7;15;27;30;26
66;4;12;15;16;17;19;11
67;6;7;9;12;17;19;27
68;12;17;25;27;32;33;36
69;6;19;20;26;27;35;21
70;6;15;21;32;34;35;1
71;4;7;9;10;14;23;26
72;6;21;26;30;31;32;28
73;3;8;13;22;29;31;12
74;6;8;13;15;27;34;5
75;8;13;24;29;31;33;6
76;6;14;17;23;26;32;21
77;4;9;15;16;23;32;13
78;1;8;13;23;27;33;24
79;1;13;16;26;29;32;6
80;9;12;16;22;24;35;32
81;8;9;18;19;23;28;20
82;1;6;7;20;28;29;32
83;8;17;22;25;26;31;11
84;3;11;18;24;26;29;1
85;10;11;13;21;27;30;6
86;2;13;23;25;30;35;29
87;14;16;17;25;29;30;4
88;7;8;12;22;25;31;16
89;16;23;24;27;32;33;19
90;6;16;18;25;27;28;7
91;13;15;17;19;24;32;6
92;1;12;15;19;27;34;36
93;3;6;7;9;18;33;31
94;6;11;12;14;21;29;23
95;8;11;14;15;29;36;22
96;1;9;14;25;30;32;26
97;4;10;25;31;35;36;17
98;9;16;27;32;35;36;23
99;10;21;28;29;31;34;17
100;1;12;13;24;26;33;22
101;2;4;15;18;19;30;8
102;4;7;10;19;30;33;34
103;1;11;15;18;28;31;26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

res = pd.DataFrame(list(product(l1, l2, l3, l4)), columns=['b1','b2','b3','b4'])
res['b5'], res['b6'] = zip(*np.random.randint(1, 36+1, size=(len(res), 2)))
```

результат:

```
In [135]: res
Out[135]:
    b1  b2  b3  b4  b5  b6
0   32   1  23  29  35   7
1   32   1  23   8  18   3
2   32   1  23  28  19  11
3   32   1  12  29  13  27
4   32   1  12   8  30  27
5   32   1  12  28  21  22
6   32   1  15  29  20  10
7   32   1  15   8  34  24
8   32   1  15  28  26  30
9   32  22  23  29  36   1
..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
71  27  22  15  28  23  36
72  27  13  23  29  29   1
73  27  13  23   8  23  13
74  27  13  23  28  33  33
75  27  13  12  29  15  34
76  27  13  12   8  17  23
77  27  13  12  28  19  17
78  27  13  15  29  33   4
79  27  13  15   8  27  14
80  27  13  15  28  22  18

[81 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: Начинающим потребовалось бы много времени, чтобы самостоятельно "дойти" до этого решения. @MaxU +1

Comment: один момент нужно подправить. В игре все шары уникальны. При генерации 5-го и 6-го шаров не делается проверка шаров на уникальность. В твоем же примере есть такая игра - "74 27  13  23  28  33  33". Возможно ли добавить условие в zip для проверки на уникальность генерируемых числе в рамках одной игры?

Comment: @YuriyTigiev, что-то так сразу ничего более-менее элегантного на ум не приходит... Попробую еще завтра найти векторизированный способ.